# Android Studio: Action bar icons appear in design window, but not when running app

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to set up an action bar for my app in Android studio.
I've been following the Google tutorial, however for some reason, the items I put on the bar do not appear when running the app. They do however appear in the design window.

[Image of the design window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nZNy.png)

[Image of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgejC.png)

This is the XML, as copied from the Google tutorial

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
    android:title="@string/action_favorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

here's the complete code of the main activity, at the bottom of which I attempt to use the action bar items.

```
package php.comget_all.ipeelu.httpweb_service_test.intenseapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Stack;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button sendButton;
public EditText editText;
public Stack<TableRow> messageStack;
public LinearLayout messagesDisplayLayout;
public ScrollView scroller;
private TextView response;
private EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
private Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

private Client client;

// Boolean telling us whether a download is in progress, so we don't trigger overlapping
// downloads with consecutive button clicks.
private boolean mDownloading = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    client = new Client("10.0.2.2", 12345, this);
    client.execute();

    messagesDisplayLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.messageDisplay);
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    scroller = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length() != 0)
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
            else
                sendButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
    messageStack = new Stack<TableRow>();
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String ts = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    TextView messageTV = new TextView(this);
    messageTV.setText(ts + ": " + message);
    messageTV.setTextSize(20);
    TableRow messageRow = new TableRow(this);
    messageRow.setPadding(0,20,0,0);
    messageRow.addView(messageTV);
    messageTV.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    messageTV.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    messagesDisplayLayout.addView(messageRow);
    messageStack.push(messageRow);
    editText.getText().clear();
    scroller.fullScroll(scroller.FOCUS_DOWN);

    //client.sendMessage(message);
    synchronized (client.thingy)
    {
        client.message = message;
        client.thingy.notify();
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_favorite:
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            return true;

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
}
```

I'm sorry if I make any rookie mistakes, I'm as new to Android Studio as can be. However I've looked this up and really couldn't find a working answer anywhere, so this is my last resort.

Comment: Action Bar is deprecated you should be using Toolbar but show where you inflate the menu to the Action Bar

Comment: Put your activity or fragment complete code

Comment: paste the java code here.Are you using setHasOptionsMenu(true) and overriding onCreateOptionsMenu ?

Comment: Implement onCreateOptionsMenu ()

Comment: Thank you so much dudes, you're amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never inflate the menu, you need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Example

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```